# Manipulation events makes buttons stop working

Tags: wpf, touch

I am developing a touch application on a workstation that doesn't have touch. I have set up a swipe manipulation to move forward and backward in my application. The problem is that now the button's won't click. Is there a way to do manipulation at the Page level and still have the button commands executed properly?

```
    private void OnElementManipulationStarting(object sender, ManipulationStartingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.ManipulationContainer = (sender as FrameworkElement);
    }
```

Comment: Could you poste some code. How do you capture touch events?

Comment: WPF Manipulation events. I'm using ManipulationStarting, ManipulationDelta, and ManipulationCompleted.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit complex. Looks like when manipulation is activated the button receives TouchDown events but as the manipulation steals the TouchDevices TouchUp never fires on the Button.

The solution I found is to attach a specific behavior on the button control that will capture the device befor the manipulation starts:

```
public class ForceCaptureBehavior: Behavior<FrameworkElement>
{

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        AssociatedObject.TouchDown += OnTouchDown;
    }

    void OnTouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        e.TouchDevice.Capture(AssociatedObject);
        e.Handled = true;
    }

}
```

Now your button will look like this:

```
<s:SurfaceButton Content="Click!" Width="200" Height="150" Click="Button_Click">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:ForceCaptureBehavior/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</s:SurfaceButton>
```

You will need to add Windows.System.Interactivity ans Microsoft.Expression.Interactions assemblies to your project.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution where I don't have to decorate EVERY SINGLE UI control with a behavior.

Comment: Well in this case attach the manipulation event handlers to an element that is in the background of your UI but not its continer.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to work through something like this today...
In your manipulation handler, like OnManipulationCompleted, if you decide there is no actual manipulation because, say, the e.TotalManipulation.Translation.X is too small to be a swipe, then call **e.Cancel()** and the normal Button handlers will be called.